# Why data added in to array multiple times?

Tags: ios, json, loops, nsmutablearray

I load data from json and then add it to nsmutablearray like this:

```
- (void)loadData
{

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{


            // Create array to hold dictionaries
            myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/json.php"]];

            if(jsonData != nil)
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                if (error == nil){

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                        // values in foreach loop
                        for (NSMutableArray *tempArray in jsonObjects) {

                            [myObject addObject:tempArray];

                            NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id.doubleValue" ascending:NO];
                            [myObject sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];


                            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                        }

                    });

                }

            }


    });

}
```

if I check with NSLog "`tempArray`" it's looks ok, but if I check "`myObject`", data added to it multiple times. How to add data just one time in to my "`myObject`" array?

EDIT:

My JSON result:

```
    [{"id":"7","title":"monkey","thumb":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/8\/e09\/5045427_thumb.jpg","url":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/8\/e09\/5045427_large.jpg","day":"perjantai","date":"0","likes":"2","device_id":"1111","active":"1"},

{"id":"11","title":"Bukashka","thumb":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/f\/b3b\/5078973_thumb.jpg","url":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/f\/b3b\/5078973_large.jpg","day":"perjantai","date":"0","likes":"1","device_id":"1111","active":"1"},

{"id":"12","title":"blya","thumb":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/f\/c1d\/5076251_thumb.jpg","url":"http:\/\/icon.s.photosight.ru\/img\/f\/c1d\/5076251_large.jpg","day":"perjantai","date":"0","likes":"1","device_id":"1111","active":"1"}]
```

My NSLog(@"%@", myObject);

```
2013-06-12 18:45:52.228 testApp[960:60b] (
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 7;
        likes = 2;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_thumb.jpg";
        title = monkey;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_large.jpg";
    }
)
2013-06-12 18:45:52.230 testApp[960:60b] (
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 11;
        likes = 1;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/b3b/5078973_thumb.jpg";
        title = Bukashka;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/b3b/5078973_large.jpg";
    },
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 7;
        likes = 2;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_thumb.jpg";
        title = monkey;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_large.jpg";
    }
)
2013-06-12 18:45:52.237 testApp[960:60b] (
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 12;
        likes = 1;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/c1d/5076251_thumb.jpg";
        title = blya;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/c1d/5076251_large.jpg";
    },
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 11;
        likes = 1;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/b3b/5078973_thumb.jpg";
        title = Bukashka;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/f/b3b/5078973_large.jpg";
    },
        {
        active = 1;
        date = 0;
        day = perjantai;
        "device_id" = 1111;
        id = 7;
        likes = 2;
        thumb = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_thumb.jpg";
        title = monkey;
        url = "http://icon.s.photosight.ru/img/8/e09/5045427_large.jpg";
    }
)
```

**WORKING SOLUTION BY: danypata**

in `viewDidLoad` put `myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

then

```
- (void)loadData
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/json.php"]];
            if(jsonData != nil)
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                if (error == nil){

                    [myObject removeAllObjects];
                    for (NSMutableDictionary *tempDict in jsonObjects) {

                        [myObject addObject:tempDict];
                    }


                    NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id.doubleValue" ascending:NO];
                    [myObject sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                        [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
                    });
                }
            }

        });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause of your problem is that the `tempArray` arrays contains same objects, but to reply to your question `how to add just one time in to my "myObject" array" there are two easy solutions

One, use `containsObject:` method like this:

```
 if([myObject containsObject:tempArray] == NO) {
    [myObject addObject:tempArray]
 }
```

Second, which I think is more elegant use `NSMutableSet` (`NSMutableSet adds objects only if the object is not already added). You can use it like this:

```
 NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
 [set addObject:tempArray];
 //after you added all objects just do the following after you init your myObject
 [myObject addObjectsFromArray:[set allObjects]]
```

**EDIT**

Your problem is caused by the `for` loop. You are nto extracting properly the data, in your JSON you have an array of dictionaries not an array of arrays so you should change the `for` loop like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *tempDict in jsonObjects) {
   [myObject addObject:tempDict];
   //other operations here 
}
```

Comment: I tried first one and it doesn't work for me. If I put this  if([myObject containsObject:jsonObjects] == NO) {
                                [myObject addObject:tempArray];
                                 NSLog(@"test");
                            } It gives me 3 times "test".

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Form what I see in your question, don't check if the myObject contains `jsonObjects`, check if contains tempArray. Your `myObject` will nenver contain `jsonObjects` because you never add it to the array

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean like this: if([myObject containsObject:tempArray] == NO) {
    [myObject addObject:tempArray];
 }

Comment: I have 3 objects in my json result and it add 3 times this 3 objects in to my array

Comment: @PavelKaljunen can you post your JSON, I think it will be faster to find a solution :)

Comment: When I changed array to dictionary in loop nothing changed, same problem.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Move `myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` exactly before the for.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31684/discussion-between-danypata-and-pavel-kaljunen)